# How do I find names (in "Firstname Surname" format) from a text using RegExp in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes the filename from the user, reads the file, finds names (in "Firstname Surname" format), saves them to a dictionary, arranges the names alphabatically, assigns each name a code ('AB', 'CD', 'EF', etc) (while making sure that if a name appears more than once in the text, it only gets 'secret coded' once), then replaces the names with these codes and saves the new file with a new name and also prints the dictionary.

```
import re
import os


def anonymize_text():

""" Taking the filename as user input """

print("Input the file name:")
filename = input()

""" Declaring a global variable in which all the matches will be stored """

global a

"""Declaring the dictionary as global so that it can be accessed from anywhere in the code """

global diction
diction = {}

""" Opening the file to read line by line """

filereader = open(filename)
h = filereader.readlines()

""" Converting the read text into a string """

c = (''.join(str(x) for x in h))

""" Defining RegEx to find the desired pattern """

d = re.compile("([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)")

""" Calling the findall() method to get a list of all the matches. It can have duplicate entries for the same string
if the matched string occurs more than once in the text being searched. """

a = re.findall(d, c)

""" Eliminating the duplicate entries """

lst = list(set(a))

""" Sorting the list alphabetically """

sortlst = (sorted(lst))

""" The list of codes to be used for anonymization """

code = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL', 'MN', 'OP', 'QR', 'ST', 'UV', 'WX', 'YZ']

""" Removing the extra '' from the list of matches and adding them as keys to the dictionary with a default value
for 'values' """

diction = {(x[0] + " " + x[1]): 0 for x in sortlst}

""" Replacing the default 'values' with the appropriate code and printing the dictionary to the console """

length = len(diction)
var = 0
if var <= length:
    for p in diction.keys():
        diction.update({p: code[var]})
        var += 1
print(diction)

""" Slicing the file extension from the filename entered by the user and adding '_anonymized.ext' to it """

newname = filename[:-4:1]
ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
exten = ext[1]
newfilename = newname+"_anonymized"+exten

""" Creating a new file and writing the text from the original file to it. """

newfilereader = open(newfilename, "w")
newfilereader.write(c)
newfilereader.close()

""" Opening the new file again to replace the names with codes and then closing all files.
 I tried a lot of different methods but couldn't get the names properly replaced in the text. If the write function
 was taken out of the loop, it would show only the last code of the dictionary replacing every name."""

u = open(newfilename, "w")
global n
for l, m in diction.items():
    n = re.sub(d, m, c)
    u.write(n)
u.close()
filereader.close()


anonymize_text()
```

I want the code to replace the each of Keys of the dictionary with their respective values. At the moment it is printing the entire text as many times as the length of the dictionary and replacing all the keys with one value in each iteration. What am I doing wrong?
Note: If I take 'u.write(n)' out of the 'for loop', then it only replaces the keys with the last value of the dictionary.

Comment: Nothing in your problem description suggests you need to know what part of the input is a first or last name. So just process each line, trimming the line endings. If you do need to know, regexes are probably not the answer here - you’d break on many valid names (“Ludwig Von Beethoven”, “Michael O’Leary”, or anything in a non-Western script). Just split the line on the first whitespace character instead.

Comment: Ah, if the input is any text, rather than a list of names, then this sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment. Real world processing should not assume simple First Last names.

Comment: @Zastai yes it is a homework assignment. We are supposed to assume that the text will only contain names in "Firstname Surname" format in English script.

Comment: Fair enough. Then @murphy1310 has you covered :)

Comment: I still need just a little bit of help in the replacing of keys with values. I've updated my question. If you can give me some insight, it would be awesome.

Comment: The last bit is failing because you assign a new variable with each replacement. Use `c = re.sub(l, m, c)` (although regular string replace is probably better) and then write `c` to the output file. Please do get in the habit of using clearer variable names, especially when asking for help. These single letter ones make your code harder to read.

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide input file content, so I picked the text from one of the links you shared.

```
c = """Suddenly, Mary Poppins flew away with her umbrella
Later in the day, John Johnson did something."""
d = re.compile("([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)")
a = re.findall(d, c)
print(a)
```

output is a list of tuples:

```
[('Mary', 'Poppins'), ('John', 'Johnson')]
```

**convert this to dictionary using dictionary comprehension**:

```
dictionary = {(x[0] + " " + x[1]):(x[0][0]+x[1][0]) for x in a}
dictionary
```

output:

```
{'John Johnson': 'JJ', 'Mary Poppins': 'MP'}
```

Here, I just assigned the initials as the code as the logic behind how to choose the code is not mentioned.

Also, by having the "first last" pattern as key in the dictionary, we ensure only one entry is made into the dictionary for a given unique full name.

**Make a list of codes**:

```
list_codes = list(dictionary.values())
list_codes
```

output:

```
['JJ', 'MP']
```

**sort the codes list**:

```
list_codes = sorted(list_codes)
```

**Save into a new file**:

```
file = open(“newfilename.txt”,”w”) 
file.write(str(list_codes)) 
file.close()
```

Comment: At the very least use something like `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` so that names like José Nuñez also work.

Comment: What has lower and upper got to do with José Nuñez? By the way, José Nuñez would anyway not work because of accented characters. Need a totally different regex to get that working.

Comment: Yes that’s what the character classes are for. I expect them to match upper and lowercase Unicode letters, not just A-Z.

Comment: Again, even if you use character classes, José Nuñez wouldn't work. Please share a working regex to support your argument.

Comment: Ah, looks like Python, even 3.7, does not do either `[[:lower:]]` or `\p{Lower}` using the standard `re` module. Disappointing. The `regex` module, however, does. And both do what I said: match Unicode characters. So if you install that module and do `import regex as re`, then either `re.compile(r'(\p{Upper}\p{Lower}*)\s+(\p{Upper}\p{Lower}*)')` or `re.compile(r'([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)\s+([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)')` will match both `'Hello World'` and `'José Nuñez'` just fine.

Comment: To use your example, `c = """Suddenly, Mary Poppins flew away with her umbrella
Later in the day, John Johnson did something. José Nuñez initially felt left out."""; d = re.compile(r'(\p{Upper}\p{Lower}*)\s+(\p{Upper}\p{Lower}*)'); a = re.findall(d, c); print(a)` outputs `[('Mary', 'Poppins'), ('John', 'Johnson'), ('José', 'Nuñez')]` when using the regex module.

Comment: @murphy1310 Thanks a lot! your hints were very helpful! With your help, I'm very close to the perfect answer!